# Php AES ECB encryption java decryption not working

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, aes

I am writing an android application which connects to php web service. Actually there is a similar ios application  working well, I am cloning it.

Between php and ios they use AES encryption/decryption. It works well. But with java encryption is ok but decryption is not working.Java encrypts and php understands but when php makes the encryption my java code is not good enough.  I am writing below codes.

can anyone guide me, help me ?

PHP encryption :

```
 echo base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                                $key,
                                outputstring,
                                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
                                nil));
```

IOS decryption :

```
ccStatus = CCCrypt( encryptOrDecrypt,
                   kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                   kCCOptionECBMode,
                   (const void *)[symmetricKey bytes],
                   kCCKeySizeAES256,
                   nil,
                   (const void *) [plainText bytes],
                   plainTextBufferSize,
                   (void *)bufferPtr,
                   bufferPtrSize,
                   &movedBytes
                   );
```

Java Decryption -NOT WORKING WELL-  Not working means, using same data, same encryption, same key i can not get same output.

```
                SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES/ECB/NoPadding, "BC");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
                result = decrypt(cipher, input);
```

I am looking an ideal solution for java decryption ? All helps are welcome ?

Comment: Did you tried encryption and then decryption using the AES/ECB/NoPadding algorithm in Java?Make sure this work!

Comment: I am sending data using AES/ECB/PCKS7Padding encryption it works. But encryption and decryption is done via above code from php side.

Comment: Define 'not working'. Do you get an exception? If so, post stack trace. Are you sure you are using the same key? You mention both `NoPadding` and `PKCS7Padding`, you need to use one or the other, not mix them.

Comment: Not working means, using same data, same encryption, same key i can not get same output.